# Score++ increasing score by 4, not by 1

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

For some reason, after a collision occurs, the score in my game goes up by 4 when it should only go up by 1 seeing as how I'm using `score++`:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (playerCategory | gainCategory)) {
        score++;
        scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)score];
        [contact.bodyB.node removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

It was working right before but just started doing this and i don't know why. What's causing the score to go up by four instead of one? I can provide more code on request.

Comment: How have you defined `score`?

Comment: Score is defined in the header file by @property (nonatomic) NSInteger *score;

Comment: collision detection can go off multiple times, you probably want to separate the entities before incrementing the score, or have a cooldown where units dont collide for 2ish seconds after contact

Comment: If score is a pointer as you show then score++ will increment the pointer by 4 on 32-bit app and 8 on 64-bit app since you are incrementing a pointer. Do you really mean for there to be an asterisk in the property?

Comment: @BrianWalker That was the problem, got rid of that and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSInteger` is an atomic type, not an object type. You've declared a pointer to it. When you increment a pointer it goes up by `sizeof(type)`. You must be testing on a 32-bit machine.

Advice then: remove the asterisk so as not to declare a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your method might be called multiple times.  Set a breakpoint or NSLog call in the method to see how many times it gets called.  Or possibly your score parameter is updated somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I did NSLog and its only being called once.

Comment: check to see if your score param is being updated in another part of your code.

Comment: ah I see, you have count declared as a pointer.  Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are, didBeginContact is indeed being called 4 times (As mentioned you should debug to confirm this). This is usually caused by two objects are "grazing" each other. One solution is to use a type of "time out" after the first collision with a body. You should also look at your values for restitution. And a small note, the reason this might occur abruptly is framerate, especially if you're using framerate-independant movement

Comment: multiple contacts can also occur when the body is composed of multiple shapes, or a convex shape split up into multiple concave shapes